# Searching for a substring match in a string list with 2 lists

Tags: python, regex, list, substring

I have 2 lists that I'm trying to work with.  The first is a nameList that corresponds to names that I want to find a match within and the second list is a status of that named list.  I want to be able to look through the 1st list and look for a match within the string and if there is a match grab the element in the first list into a new list and also grab the corresponding element in the second list to get a name and status pair.  I've tried several approaches at this and have not been able to get it right and have looked at various list comprehension questions on the board and haven't been able to find a solution that works for my case.

For example in the code below, I would like to grab the 'abc-1' and 'abc-2' entries as well as the 'ok' and 'ok' status for both of those entries and output those as the finalNameList and finalStatusList.

I'd be grateful for any help anyone could provide.

In my current implementation I am getting a 
type error : 'expected string or buffer'

```
import re
import os
import sys
import getopt
import pdb

nameList = ['abc-1', 'abc-2', 'def-1', 'def-2']
statusList = ['ok', 'ok', 'bad', 'bad']
scac = 'abc'


def scacFilter (scac, nameList, statusList):
    if not scac:
        newNameList = nameList
        newStatusList = statusList
    else:
        for i in nameList:
            if re.search(scac, i):
                name = nameList[i]
                status = statusList[i]
                newNameList.append(name)
                newStatusList.append(status)
            else:
                print 'no scac match'
    return newNameList, newStatusList


finalNameList, finalStatusList = scacFilter(scac, nameList, statusList)
```

Comment: `i` is an integer. So you're searching for the string `scac` in an integer `i`. Instead of `for i in range(len(nameList)):` just do `for i in nameList`.

Comment: Don't use indices, use `zip`. Eg, `for name, status in zip(nameList, statusList):`

Comment: Will the `scac` string always be at the start of a `nameList` string when it matches? If so, don't use regex, use `name.startswith(scac)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
import os

nameList = ['abc-1', 'abc-2', 'def-1', 'def-2']
statusList = ['ok', 'ok', 'bad', 'bad']
scac = 'abc'


def scacFilter (scac, nameList, statusList):
    resultList = []
    resultVal = []
    for val in nameList:
        if not val.find(scac):
            indexVal = nameList.index(val)
            resultList.append(nameList[indexVal])
            resultVal.append(statusList[indexVal])
    return resultList, resultVal
finalNameList, finalStatusList = scacFilter(scac, nameList, statusList)
print finalNameList
print finalStatusList
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` is an integer. So the regular expression is searching for the string defined in `scac` in an integer value. i.e. it's searching for `'abc'` in `1`.

A better way to create your for loop would be:

```
for i in nameList:
```

This way, `i` is actually the string in `nameList` (i.e. `'abc-1'`, `'abc-2'`, etc...) and not an integer, thus you'll be performing your regex on the string you intend to!

Comment: Thank you for catching that, I'm pretty new to Python.  I can't believe I missed that.   One quick follow up question, I modified the code as recommended.   I'm a bit unclear how to access the "status" that is at the same indices.  Any guidance on how to pull the status out at that indices would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can simply use the index() method on nameList with nameList.index(‘abc-1’) and then use the resulting integer value to access that index of your other list. Apologies for the lack of syntax highlighting, I’m on my phone now.

Comment: @jeff if this answers your question could you please accept the answer so that others can see it in the future if they end up in the same predicament as you.